# How to bypass @JsonIgnore annotation?

Tags: json, jackson, swagger

I am trying to create a rest end point and using Swagger as UI representation. The pojo which I'm using it has a variable annotated with  `@JsonIgnore` as shown below.

```
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> property = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Now, when I'm providing `JSON` (with property value) to this end point and trying to read its value it is coming out as `null` (due to `@JsonIgnore`).

```
pojoObj.getProperties(); //null
```

Is there any way if I can get property value without removing the `@JsonIgnore` annotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by utilizing Jackson's [Mixin](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature, where you create another class that cancels the ignore annotation. You can then "attach" the mixin to the `ObjectMapper` at run time:

This is the POJO I used:

```
public class Bean
{
    // always deserialized
    public String name;

    // ignored (unless...) 
    @JsonIgnore
    public Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
```

This is the "other" class. It is just another POJO with the **same** property name

```
public class DoNotIgnore
{
    @JsonIgnore(false)
    public Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

a Jackson Module is used to tie the bean to the mixin:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DoNotIgnoreModule extends SimpleModule
{
    public DoNotIgnoreModule() {
        super("DoNotIgnoreModule");
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context)
    {
        context.setMixInAnnotations(Bean.class, DoNotIgnore.class);
    }
}
```

Tying it all together:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String json = "{\"name\": \"MyName\","
            +"\"properties\": {\"key1\": \"val1\", \"key2\": \"val2\", \"key3\": \"val3\"}"
            + "}";

    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // decide at run time whether to ignore properties or not
        if ("do-not-ignore".equals(args[0])) {
            mapper.registerModule(new DoNotIgnoreModule());
        }
        Bean bean = mapper.readValue(json, Bean.class);
        System.out.println(" Name: " + bean.name + ", properties " + bean.properties);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```